# Can a conditional be passed in JavaScript method as parameter?

Tags: javascript

Wondered if this works or makes any sense in JavaScript:

```
if(word.includes("." || "!")) -- in context:

let howManyDots = [];

let punctuationCounter = storyWords.forEach(word => {
  if(word.includes("." || "!")) {
    howManyDots++;
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried whether it works?

Comment: I did, but from what I understood looking at the result, only the "." is taken in as parameter and then the conditional and "!" are skipped. I was unsure if this was the case, or it could be done somehow, cause I think it helps to simplify code in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. The expression `"." || "!"` evaluates to `"."`, so that's what you're passing to `.includes`. You have to do:

```
word.includes(".") || word.includes("!");
```

To generalise:

```
[".", "!"].some( char => word.includes( char ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `word.includes(".") || word.includes("!")`

Since you are expecting a `return` value, you can use `filter` instead of `forEach`. Use `length` to get the array count.

```js
let storyWords = ['apple', 'javascr!pt', 'dot.'];
let punctuationCounter = storyWords.filter(word => {
  return word.includes(".") || word.includes("!");
}).length;

console.log(punctuationCounter);
```

---

**You can make it shorter as:**

```
let punctuationCounter = storyWords.filter(word => word.includes(".") || word.includes("!") ).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, the expression `"." || "!"` will be evaluated before it is passed to the function , you can test the case with following example

```js
let foo = (p) => console.log(p)
foo("." || "h")
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not support this syntax.
The "closest" you will find are methods like `Math.min` which accepts an infinite set of parameters :
`Math.min(0, 2, 52, -1)`

But `String.prototype.includes` allow for only one string argument.
See API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional like | as **or** in a regex `/\.|!/.test(str)` but not in `includes()`

```js
var str = "sometex!";

console.log(/\.|!/.test(str));
```

By the way, with more than one thing to match, it's better for me using `.test`

In your code would be something like:

```
if(/\.|!/.test(word)) {
    howManyDots++;
  }
```

You could also use `match` and `length` like this:

```js
var str = "sometex!....";

var howManyDots = (str.match(/\.|!/g)).length;

console.log(howManyDots);
```

If you have an array of strings:

```js
var arr = ["sometex!....", "sometex2!!!!","sometex2!!.", "sometex2!", , "sometex2"];

howManyDots = (arr.join().match(/\.|!/g)).length

console.log(howManyDots);
```